# Close Window without code-behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

Is it possible to bind a `Button` to Close the `Window` without adding a code-behind event?

```
<Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding CloseWithSomeKindOfTrick}" />
```

Instead of the following XAML:

```
<Button Content="OK" Margin="0,8,0,0" Click="Button_Click">
```

With the code-behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574214/2132796) answer.

Comment: This is asked earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501886/how-should-the-viewmodel-close-the-form/2100824#2100824 may help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want close the dialog `Window`, you can add for Button `IsCancel` property:

```
<Button Name="CloseButton"
        IsCancel="True" ... />
```

This means the following [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.iscancel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When you set the `IsCancel` property of a Button to true, you create a Button that is registered with the AccessKeyManager. *The button is then activated when a user presses the ESC key*.

Now, if you click on this Button, or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then dialog `Window` is closing, but it does not work for the normal `MainWindow`.

To close the `MainWindow`, you can simply add a Click handler which has already been shown. But if you want a more elegant solution that would satisfy the MVVM style you can add the *attached* behavior:

```
public static class ButtonBehavior
{
    #region Private Section

    private static Window MainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;

    #endregion

    #region IsCloseProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCloseProperty;

    public static void SetIsClose(DependencyObject DepObject, bool value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(IsCloseProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsClose(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (bool)DepObject.GetValue(IsCloseProperty);
    }

    static ButtonBehavior()
    {
        IsCloseProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsClose",
                                                              typeof(bool),
                                                              typeof(ButtonBehavior),
                                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsCloseTurn));
    }

    #endregion

    private static void IsCloseTurn(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue) == true)
        {
            if (MainWindow != null)
                MainWindow.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown);

            var button = sender as Button;

            if (button != null)
                button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
        }
    }

    private static void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow.Close();
    }

    private static void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            MainWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

And in `MainWindow` use this Behavior like as:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProjectNamespace.MainWindow" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace">

    <Button Name="CloseButton"
            local:ButtonBehavior.IsClose="True" ... />
```